# Regular expression for strings with alphanumeric, spaces and one special character

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to write a regular expression that detects a string with the following conditions:

- Cannot be empty
- Needs to contains at least 1 alphabetic character.
- Can contains (or not) spaces
- Can contains (or not) the special characters `' - _` .

Looking at similar questions, I have been able to write this:

```
grepl(pattern="(^[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+$)", mylistofstrings) #do not resognize '
grepl("'",data$last_nm ) #I search for ' here
```

Any ideas of how to do it?  I am using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the (what you call) special characters to the allowed characters in the character class.  Anything inside the outmost `[...]` is a list of individual characters which you allow; and the `+` quantifier requires one or more repetitions of this single-character pattern.

However, in order to meet the requirement for at least one alphabetic character, you can refactor to "anything in the list of required and optional characters, followed by one alphabetic character, followed by anything in the list of required or optional characters" where the groups adjacent to the one required character are allowed to be empty.

```
grepl(pattern="(^[-'_[:alpha:][:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]][-'_[:alpha:][:blank:]]*$)", mylistofstrings)
```

The minus in the character class is tricky because it needs to be first or last (you can't say `['-_]` because that means any character whose ASCII code is between that of `'` and the ASCII code of `_`; it needs to be `[-'_]` or `['_-]`); other than that, the order inside the square brackets is arbitrary.

Comment: hi, works fine. I just chaged [:alnum:] by [:alpha:] as I don't want numbers. I don't understand your last sentence, it works fine with the minus in the middle. Eg "t-f" is TRUE

Comment: The regex class `[a-z]` matches `a` through `z` while `[-az]` matches any one of the three characters `-`, `a`, and `z`.

Comment: oh, you are right. "-" this is a TRUE and it shouldnt. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't think you are receiving properly; I was talking about how to express a character class containing a minus, while you are talking about the string you are testing with.  But yeah, my original regex matched any one out of all of these characters; see updated answer now.